# Can anyone explain the output of this C code?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int x = 1, y = 0, z = 5;
    int a = x && y || z++;
    printf("%d", z);
}
```

On executing, the following program gives output as 6 which is expected.
But this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int x = 1, y = 0, z = 5;
    int a = x && y && z++;
    printf("%d", z);
}
```

gives output as 5. Can anyone explain this output. I have good understanding of pre-increment and post-increment operator but couldn't able to figure out this output.

Answer (score 0):

In C,in

```
a = f(x) && g(y)
```

If f(x) evaluates to 0 we know a will always be 0 no matter what g(y) is.  g(y) will therefore not be evaluated and any side effects of g(y) will not happen.

In your case, this means the increment never happens.

Comment: How did you circumvent the answer posting requirement that the question must be open?

Comment: @machine_1 - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252711/this-answer-was-posted-after-the-question-was-closed-how-is-that-possible